# Image in github comments is not displaying

Tags: github, github-pages, github-for-windows

[image]
[image]

I am new to github, I really don't know what is happening there.
does anyone know how to fix that problem ????

The image on github issue's comment section is not displaying correctly . It is only showing the name of Image